# Crazy randomize MS Access query

Tags: vb.net

I am really exhausted.i have this query it work very very with my Sql server database but when i put it with my MS Access database i have an error ( The index (zero base) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list ).
Sql server query :

```
Dim sql As String = String.Format(" SELECT TOP {0} ID1,Team1,Team2,Team3 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newid() ASC) AS F1, ID1, Team1, Team2 FROM Table1 ) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY newid() ASC) AS F1,Team3 FROM Table2 )  as t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1", rows)
```

MS Access query :

```
Dim sql As String = String.Format(" SELECT TOP (0) ID1,Team1,Team2,Team3 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "} ASC) AS F1,ID1,Team1,Team2 from Table1) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "} ASC) AS F1, Team3 FROM Table2 ) as t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1 ", rows)
```

My code in Form1 Load :

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Conn_Randomize()
    InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY Team2", Conn_Randomize)
    InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
    InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
    InfoTable = New DataTable()
    InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = InfoTable
End Sub
```

My code for input number of rows and columns i want to display in DataGridView2 with NumericupDown1 and 2 and randomize

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Conn_Randomize()
    Dim rows As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(NumericUpDown1.Value, rows) Then
        MsgBox("NUMBER NOT AVAILABLE", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        NumericUpDown1.Value = ""
        NumericUpDown1.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If NumericUpDown2.Value = 2 Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("SELECT Top {0} ID1, Team1, Team2 FROM Table1  ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID1)*Time())", rows)
        InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, Conn_Randomize)
        InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
        InfoTable = New DataTable()
        InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = InfoTable
    End If
    If NumericUpDown2.Value = 3 Then
        Dim sql As String = String.Format(" SELECT TOP {0} ID1,Team1,Team2,Team3 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "} ASC) AS F1,ID1,Team1,Team2 from Table1) as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY {" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & "} ASC) AS F1, Team3 FROM Table2 ) as t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1 ", rows)
        InfoCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, Conn_Randomize)
        InfoAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        InfoAdapter.SelectCommand = InfoCommand
        InfoTable = New DataTable()
        InfoAdapter.Fill(InfoTable)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = InfoTable
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `Guid.NewGuid()` produces a `Guid` and not a random value. Guids are guaranteed to be **UNIQUE**. They are not guaranteed to be **RANDOM**. You really should just load your data from the database and then randomise the results in memory using an appropriate RNG.

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually have a look at what `sql` contains after that second code snippet is executed? Does it make sense?

The first code snippet is using `newid`, which is a T-SQL function, which means that the database is going to generate a new `uniqueidentifier` for each row and use them to sort the data.  How could the second code snippet do the equivalent? It's calling `NewGuid` in the VB code once only and concatenating the result into the SQL code.  You're lucky that that is even valid syntax but the result is not going to be that each record has a different value to be sorted by.

You need the database to generate a value for each record that it can use as a sort key and the way to generate random numbers in Access SQL is with `Rnd`. I thought that you were already using that days ago.

Also, while I haven't checked, I'm not sure that `ROW_NUMBER` is supported in Access either.  It wasn't added to SQL Server all that long ago.

Comment: Yes I think Row number can not adapt with MS Access ..how to fix this problem with MS Access query please

Comment: Firstly, you haven't actually explained what you are trying to do and it's not for us to work it out from some SQL code. You should either edit this question or post a new one and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of what you're trying to achieve. Secondly, if there's no equivalent to `ROW_NUMBER` in Access (I'm not aware of one but you should be checking the documentation to find out for sure) then you'd have to approach it a quite different way in Access, e.g. query two tables separately and combine the data in your app.

Comment: I have A Table1 with 3 fields ( ID1 - Team1 - Team2 )..i have too other Table2 with 2 fields ( ID2 - Team3 ) .. i want randomize this 4 fields ( ID1 - Team1 - Team2 - Team3 ) but not ( ID2) .. and display them in DataGridView1..i will edit my question